# How I run laravel / vue web application with wamp?

Tags: laravel, wamp

I have Laravel/Vue web application and I am trying to run it on Windows with wamp. Here are the steps I did:

```
npm install
npm run production
```

I get that app.js compiled successfully. and then I ran

```
composer install
php artisan serve
```

I get url `127.0.0.1:8000` but when I browse to this url I get 500 server error. I also tried to add the public folder to virtual host but I got same result 500 server error. What I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have followed all the configuration settings for the project like the permissions for storage folder, `.env` settings etc?

I would suggest using [Laragon](https://laragon.org/) for windows, its pretty simple and works best with all type of Laravel applications.

Comment: .env does not exists only .env.example is this the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate app keys?

`php artisan key:generate`

Comment: this should be comment but not answer

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I didn't have enough reputation to comment :)